# How to avoid store same values on DB

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: example]

Considering my firebase DB:

How I ensure the email (or other field) uniqueness at firebase side (using rules)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you in stead of using the unique id generated by the `push()` method, to use the email address. Because Firebase does not accept symbols as `.` in the key, you'll need to encode the email address like this:

> name@email.com -> name@email,com

As you probably see, the `.` symbol is changed with `,`. To `encode` and `decode` the email address, i suggest you use this methods:

```
static String encodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(".", ",");
}

static String decodeUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    return userEmail.replace(",", ".");
}
```

Than to verify the `uniqueness` of your users, just put a `listener` on the `users` node and use the `exists()` method on the `dataSnapshot`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I thought I had others choices... It's a little weird replace point by comma and etc... no?

Comment: This is an efficient solution and also a good practice when structuring a user section in Firebase. You can wait for others answers but if you think that my answer helped you, consider accepting it and giving a +1. Thanks!